# How to limit NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle

Tags: nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have this in my code:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *currency = [defaults objectForKey:@"currencySymbol"];

    NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:currencySymbol withString:@""];
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:currency];

    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[text intValue]*0.01];
    text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
    textField.text = text;
```

and it works great until you reach a certain amount, then it can't go higher, for example:

- 2,500.00 (is possible)
- 25,000.00 (it´s not possible)

Maybe it´s something stupid, could anyone alert me what is that i am not seeing?

Thanks.

For those who are having the same problem, we have to add this line of code:

```
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

Because (logically) the `,` is used for thousands...

Comment: Why is 25,000.00 not possible?

Comment: Hello Andrew, thanks for answering, well that´s what i´m trying to figure it out...just right know i tried to imput 20,000.00 and the maximum that i get is 2,000.00.

Comment: for those who are having the same problem:

Comment: So did that line fix your problem?